# flux limiter problem

Tags: finite-element, matlab

I have worked with MATLAB for calculating below equation for any time ($n$) and place($i$). In this equation, flux limiter is used.

$$C(i,n+1)=C(i,n)-V\left[1+\frac{1}{2}\psi(r_i)-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(r_i-1)}\psi(r_i-1)\right]\left(C(i,n)-C(i-1,n)\right)$$

By writing the equation, the amount of flux limiter in the time zero ($n=0$) faced problem.

As you know, $r_i=\frac{C(i+1,n)-C(i,n)}{C(i,n)-C(i-1,n)}$, which the amount of $C$ in the time zero ($n=0$) for all places ($i$) is the same, then I reached undefined value ($0/0$) for $r$ in time zero($n=0$).

Is there any equation or any amount for calculating $r$ in the time of zero?

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite the limiter into a form that avoids division by zero, by checking the nominator and denominator with a couple of 'if' statements.

Alternatively, you can add a small number with the appropriate sign:
$$r_i = \frac{C(i+1,n)-C(i,n) \pm \epsilon}{C(i,n)-C(i-1,n) \pm \epsilon}$$
where $\epsilon$ is a small positive constant, that should be added to a positive term and subtracted from a negative term, to prevent $r_i$ from changing sign.